# Python returns wrong answer for list inclusion

Tags: python, multithreading, list, if-statement

I have a class with some methods, and a dict of dicts `E` which is shared between threads. I use the `Threading.lock()` class  (instantiated as `Elock`) to read and write from `E` each time I need to.

One of the methods within the class looks like this:

```
Elock.acquire()
#print self.Num, E[key].keys()
if self.Num not in E[key].keys():
    print '\n\nDisappeared!\n\n', self.Num, E[key].keys()
    #DO STUFF
    Elock.release()
    return
else:
    Elock.release()
```

What is really blowing my mind is that I will get

```
Disappeared!

17171875.0 [17175000.0, 17171875.0]
```

When I uncomment the print command before the conditional, I get what I'm expecting:

17171875.0 [17175000.0, 17171875.0]

As you can see, in both cases `self.Num` is in `E[key].keys`. Why is the conditional returning `True` and entering `if` clause?

Sometimes `self.Num` will be a `float` and the corresponding element in `E[key].keys()` will be an `int`. This should not be an issue anyway, and I think is not causing my problem. When I write

```
if float(self.Num) not in [float(x) for x in E[key].keys()]:
```

Also, a commenter suggested I not use floats. I tried this:

```
if int(self.Num) not in [int(x) for x in E[key].keys()]:
```

but in both cases the behavior does not change.

Most puzzling is that IT ONLY BREAKS SOMETIMES! It works normally most of the time, but seems to return the wrong answer if the number ends with 5.0 (at least, that is the only time I have seen it break).

Comment: Never do equality check (and hence inclusion checks) with floating point numbers. Floating point numbers are only **approximately** equal (sometimes).

Comment: I'm testing with `int` rather than `float` now, hopefully it's that simple. If what you say is right, why does typing `17171875.0 in [17175000.0, 17171875.0]` into an interpreter return `True`?

Comment: @Wapiti:  Are any of those numbers the result of a calculation?

Comment: @Steven Rumblaski: They are not. They are prices taken from a market data feed. `E` stores new prices as they come in. The prices go through all sorts of procedures though, like being sent through a `zero message queue` socket, and being checked over and over.

Comment: @SuperSaiyan: Unfortunately trying with `int` did not solve anything.

Comment: Change `print '\n\nDisappeared!\n\n', self.Num, E[key].keys()` to `print '\n\nDisappeared!\n\n', repr(self.Num), map(repr, E[key].keys())`.  You should see that the numbers are not the same.  To see what I mean try `a, b = 17171875.0, 17171874.999999998;print a == b, a, b, repr(a), repr(b)`

Comment: @Steven Rumblaski: You cracked it. Also explains why `int` does not work, since 17141874.999999 goes to 17141874 rather than 17141875. So @SuperSaiyan was also right. Who gets points in this situation?